# two TextViews and two ListViews does not work with layout_weight Android

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

Layout Weights are not working. The two text views disappear and lists are not shown correctly. I tried 1 3 1 3 respectively and it appears not to be working as well. I tried percentage and also not working. changed wrap_content to fill parent and also not working.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/shelves_header" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/fragment_shelvesMenu_shelvesList_listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/light_grey"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/list_padding"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/list_padding" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/shelves_others" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/fragment_shelvesMenu_othersList_listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/light_grey"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/list_padding"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/list_padding" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set height for items with weight to Zero

```
android:layout_height="0dp"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this hope this works for you

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/shelves_header" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/fragment_shelvesMenu_shelvesList_listView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/light_grey"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/list_padding"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/list_padding" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/shelves_others" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/fragment_shelvesMenu_othersList_listView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/light_grey"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/list_padding"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/list_padding" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="@string/shelves_header" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/fragment_shelvesMenu_shelvesList_listView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@color/light_grey"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/list_padding"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/list_padding" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="@string/shelves_others" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/fragment_shelvesMenu_othersList_listView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@color/light_grey"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/list_padding"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/list_padding" />
```

> Try like this